# Compile function with only some variables

Tags: functions, function-construction, compile

I made the simple example below for explaining the problem. How can I compile only some variables?
For example, in the example only `a` and `b` are `Integer`, `c` can be any type.

```
In[218]:= cf = Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}, c}, a*b + c];
cf[2, 3, d]
CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument d at position 3 should be a machine-size real number.
Out[219]= 6 + d
```

How can I solve this warning and make this work for any `c`? 
I want "c" to be anything.

Comment: I do not believe what you want is possible.

Comment: "Anything" is generally not possible in `Compile`. Basically, only standard types such as machine integers, machine doubles, machine complex, and booleans (and arrays of those) are supported.

Comment: Compilation to machine code needs to know the data types. If you do not know the  type, you must compile for the most general type that is possible. E.g. if you number can be `Real` or `Integer` you must compile for  `Real` and when you call the compiled function, you must eventually convert an integer argument to real.

Comment: I want `c` to be a symbol and then I'll may plot that function with `c` from `0` to `1` for example.

Comment: "Anything" is not possible, but _type dispatching_ is, and I think this can actually be done in a clever, efficient way as long as `c` is only of primitive, compilable types.

Answer (score 6):

What you *can* do is this:

```
cf[c_] := cf[c] = With[{c = c}, Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}}, a*b + c]];
```

For a specific number `c` (it *must* have a numeric type), `cf[c]` will result in a compiled function into which the parameter `c` is hardcoded. Also `cf[c]` is cached this way. Calling it several times with the same `c`, e.g. with `cf[1][2, 3]`, `cf[1][4, 5]`, won't recompile the function. However, this trades memory for speed as the cached `CompiledFunction` objects have to be stored somewhere.

This technique can indeed make sense sometimes, because the C-code generator can optimize some expressions more aggressively if it knows the actual value of `c`. But it only makes sense if you call `cf[c]` many times.

Answer (score 5):

A follow up on Henrik's approach, which will be less optimized, but calls `Compile` fewer times if you need multiple values of `c` with the same type:

```
Clear[cfCompiled, cf];
cfCompiled[type : Integer | Real | Complex] :=
  
  cfCompiled[type] = 
   Compile[{{a, _Integer}, {b, _Integer}, {c, _type}}, a*b + c];
cf[a_, b_, c_] :=
 With[{f = cfCompiled[Head[c]]},
  f[a, b, c] /; Head[f] === CompiledFunction
  ]
```

gives stuff like

```
cf[1, 1, 1]

2

cf[1, 1, 1 + I]

2. + 1. I

cf[1, 1, 1.]

2.
```

But really you should also look into `FunctionCompile` if you need sophisticated type dispatching or something. See also [this video](https://youtu.be/O_Cu2T-6Eoo).